# I have a list of dictionaries, that have same keys and some have different values for those keys

Tags: python-3.x

```
mylist = [{'a': 'banana'}, {'a': 'orange'}, {'b': 'apple'}, {'c': 'grapes'}, {'b': 'banana'}, {'c': 'apple'}]
```

I want to change this into a dictionary with same keys to have list of value like so:

```
mylist = [{'a': 'banana', 'orange'}, {'b': 'apple', 'banana'}, {'c': 'grape' 'apple'}]
```

My code:-

```
mydict_ = defaultdict(list)

for x in mylist:
    for k, v in x.items():
        mydict_[k].append(v)

mydict = dict(mydict_)
print(mydict)
```

I am getting:-

```
mylist = [{'a': 'banana', 'banana'}, {'b': 'apple', 'apple'}, {'c': 'grapes', 'grapes'}]
```

Comment: Your current code works -- it seems to produce exactly what you want. What exactly is the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in your loop:

for x in mylist:
for k,v in x.items():
if(k in mydict):
mydict[k].append(v)
else:
mydict[k]=[v]

Comment: same result getting.
mylist = [{'a': 'banana', 'orange'}, {'b': 'apple', 'banana'}, {'c': 'grape' 'apple'}]

Comment: Isn't it what you want

Comment: mylist = [{'a': 'banana', 'orange'}, {'b': 'apple', 'banana'}, {'c': 'grape' 'apple'}]

Comment: I want this only but did not work i am getting
mylist = [{'a': 'banana', 'banana'}, {'b': 'apple', 'apple'}, {'c': 'grapes', 'grapes'}]

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_dict = defaultdict(list)
for key_value_pair in mylist:
    key, value = list(key_value_pair.items())[0]
    new_dict[key].append(value)
ans_dict = dict(new_dict)
```

Comment: same result getting. mylist = [{'a': 'banana', 'orange'}, {'b': 'apple', 'banana'}, {'c': 'grape' 'apple'}]